# CSS - Center Position Select Dropdown Arrow

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm unable to center the text and arrow of my select dropdown using pure CSS. I have tried `absolute:position` and `text-align:center`. `text-align:center` centers the text only. It looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

```
<div class="col-sm-12 mobile-controller">
   <select class="select" id="dropGroup"> 
      <option value="head"> Head/Neck </option>
      <option value="torso"> Shoulders/Torso </option>
      <option value="legs"> Legs/Hips </option>
   </select>
</div>
```

```
#mobile #dropGroup {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vw;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.select#dropGroup {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Is this using bootstrap 5?

Comment: @Adam I'm not using bootstrap 5

Comment: Where is `col-sm-12` and the rest coming from?